# Is it possible to still develop for first gen iPad? iOS 5.1.1

Tags: ios

Using a modern configuration El Capitan and Xcode 6/7 ; and get the app published on the App Store?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible?

Comment: I was under the impression that only projects built using a specific SDK/ OSX version and settings where allowed to be submissions on the store. As current versions of Xcode only allow 7.1 selectable as lowest build target unless manually editing build settings; and no developers seem to be publishing anything new that works <7.1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! 
I just developed an app that works on iOS 5.1.1 all the way to iOS 9.3, which was approved and is now available on the iTunes store.

I developed it in XCode 4.2 first, tested it on the simulator, and then moved it to the new XCode 7.3
I used Objective C, and used if else (checking for supported functionality rather than for OS versions) for OS specific API. 
for e.g. 
`if([UIAlertController class]){ 
... 
} 
else {
...
}`

Hope this helps others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, but if I'm right you have to support iOS 7 or higher aswell.

For more info see: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to develop for and deploy via the AppStore to the iPad 1 by setting your deployment target to 5.1.1. and making sure the binary contains code for the `armv7` architecture.

I was hoping that you could've use Apple's bitcode to take care of the CPU architecture requirements, but sadly it requires iOS 6 and above:

> clang: error: -fembed-bitcode is not supported on versions of iOS prior to 6.0